# Tkinter window style differs from expected style

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When i try tkinter on my 64 bit windows 10 python v3.7.4, i am getting windows layout like this:
[image]

What i am trying to achieve is a classic windows type dialog box like this:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I think this depends on the Operative System, not Tkinter...

Comment: Like @DavidDuran said, it depends on the OS your running too, if it was Mac OS X then you would receive default mac style, and for the picture that you inserted, it looks like windows 7, and a similar "style" can be achieved  by using, `ttkthemes` and the `clam` theme, but the title bar will remain same as your OS default

Comment: I tried with ironpython to only get the same result. So you guys are right its the OS. Thanks for your reply.